# PHP ini_set php.net manual display_errors example explanation

Tags: php, error-reporting

Reading [php.net's example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) of setting `display_errors` with `ini_set`:

```
<?php
echo ini_get('display_errors');

if (!ini_get('display_errors')) {
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
}

echo ini_get('display_errors');
?>
```

Is there a good reason as to why we're checking to see if `display_errors` is false before we set it to true? Surely it would be faster to not bother checking and just set it to true if that was our intention?

I would be really appreciative if someone could enlighten me on this; as should I be doing something similar with `error_reporting(-1);` too?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a good reason as to why we're checking to see if display_errors is false before we set it to true?

It's an example. No, there is no deeper reason. Overriding "true" with "true" also is valid.

> Surely it would be faster to no bother checking and just set it to true if that was our intention?

I guess you would rarely feel any difference, wether you check it first, or not.

However: You should use `php.ini` for this and more important: *Never* enable `display_errors` on a live system!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I did a quick test on my localhost, which actually seemed to indicate that if `display_errors` is already set, then it's actually *faster* to check if it's already set, than to just set it.

It's fairly trivial as I had to run a loop a million times to really notice a difference, and even then it's not much (about 10%), but it does seem to be there. I guess this would indicate that `set_ini` is doing a bit more work than `get_ini`.

Perhaps others can confirm?

I guess in practice this is pretty useless, as you'd not really want `display_errors` set to true on a live site, so micro-performance optimisation isn't so much of a concern.

Other than that, can't think of a reason as to why you'd want to check up front.

Comment: Really great answer, thank you! I know it's only a tiny amount, but just out of interest, would it be the same to check `error_reporting()` too?