# Will not redirect after submitting form - Form works, still get error

Tags: php

I have written this form, and it works perfectly. It sends the email fine. But after it sends, it errors. So people submitting the form think its broken, but it actually sends the form. All I am trying to do is redirect after the form submits to thanks.asp after the mail sends.


 Any help is appreciated.

```
<?php

    $name = trim($_POST['name']);
    $company = $_POST['company'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];

    $site_owners_email = 'support@macnx.com'; // Replace this with your own email address
    $site_owners_name = 'Landin'; // replace with your name

    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name";  
    }

    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address"; 
    }

    if (strlen($comments) < 3) {
        $error['comments'] = "Please leave a comment.";
    }

    if (!$error) {

        require_once('phpMailer/class.phpmailer.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->From = $email;
        $mail->FromName = $name;
        $mail->Subject = "Website Contact Form";
        $mail->AddAddress($site_owners_email, $site_owners_name);
        $mail->Body = $email . $company . $comments;

        // GMAIL STUFF

        $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls"; 

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = "inquiry@getgearhead.com"; // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = "..."; // SMTP password

        $mail->Send();

        header("Location: http://www.macnx.com/noflash/thanks.asp");
    }
?>
```

Comment: The error should be that the headers have already been sent.

Comment: Please post the error for us to see

Comment: As @ChrisB stated, check to see if you have a whitespace besides or above `<?php` or HTML, or any other type of output happening. If that is not the case, then it is a byte order mark issue.

Comment: If the message was *Hi* this would fail? Come on man, I just wanted to say *Hi*.

Comment: It is just a regular 500 error. I am going to check into the php logs

Comment: To see the actual error just put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` up top by the opening php tag and then run the script again.

Comment: @chrisB adding that, one sec

Comment: @chrisB i added that to the top of my php and it didnt show me anything else

Comment: @Fred I looked up what that error ment, and its beyond me. I hope it is not that.

Comment: @jackrflick try and get the error message for us, it's really hard for us to help you otherwise

Comment: @jackrflick Do you have a copy of [**Notepad++**](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), and if not, download it and run/install it. Once you did that, open it up and it will show you what the encoded format is. If it shows "Encode in UTF-8", then you will need to re-encode to "Convert to UTF-8 without BOM".

Comment: @jackrflick Here: http://notepad-plus-plus.org/

Comment: @jackrflick If and when you need to read up on the ***infamous BOM*** - a.k.a. "Byte Order Mark", you can have a look at this URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark - You can also see a few example in an accepted answer of mine on a similar issue => http://stackoverflow.com/a/18137407/1415724

Comment: @Fred Thank you very much. I am definitely going to look into both of these.

Comment: @jackrflick You're quite welcome. There is a solution, it's just in finding the right one.

Comment: @jackrflick I do have one last thing I would like you to try and it's this `header('Location: http://www.macnx.com/noflash/thanks.asp');` set inside single quotes instead of double quotes. ***"It's worth a shot."***

Comment: @jackrflick Another thing you can try is to add `exit();` after your `header...` give that a try also. Gotta look at all available options.

Comment: @jackrflick Also see this, what I found on the PHPMailer website http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=femanual#redirect which may be an option. Keep me posted on the extra info I put up. Good luck.

Comment: @Fred That did not work either. Thank though. EDIT: I meant the single quotation. Have not looked at the rest yet

Comment: @jackrflick None of my three suggestions?

Comment: Ok, so... I added my header + the exit to the TOP of the code, and it did not error out. However the email did not send.

Comment: @jackrflick And did you look into Notepad++ by any chance? Sounds to me like you've got some output happening before headers. It's gotta be that.

Comment: I cannot look at notepad++ yet, on a mac at the moment.

Comment: @jackrflick Here are a few Mac text editors with BOM support (UTF-8) http://macromates.com/ and http://www.peterborgapps.com/smultron/ and here's a question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20533/mac-text-code-editor plus an article on the Mac code/text editors http://mac360.com/2008/06/faceoff_which_is_the_best_text_editor_ever/

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you use `header();` incorrectly.

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

[PHP Documentation - header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: So should I move the header somewhere else? Maybe before the "$mail->Send();"

Comment: Header needs to be at the very top of the file

Comment: Oh, well then that is probably what my problem is. I will try a couple of things. Thanks for helping. I am aslo going to try and get the error as well.

Comment: Sorry that I can't help more. Try adding both of these lines at the top of your script in order to get the errors to show. `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: Also, try removing `header()` and see if you still get that 500 page. If you don't then you know it is certainly `header()` causing the trouble.

Comment: Yeah, I have added both of those lines of code. I still do not get the error, just the 500. I added my header at the top, still doesn't work. But, the email still sends. I am very new to PHP, but is this something that I would need to contact the web host about, not the problem itself, but seeing the errors? Sounds like that is the only way to see what is going on.

Comment: Try contacting your host, it may be some server settings that are keeping errors from showing.

Comment: @jackrflick Have a look at this question on SO, it shows different options to show errors, you may be able to override the server's settings by inserting those codes on top of your page. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11596779/php-ini-set-php-net-manual-display-errors-example-explanation

Comment: @Fred i am looking into this now.

Comment: @jackrflick Ok, keep me posted.

Comment: I pasted that code to the top of my page, and it still did not show me any error besides the 500. It seems to me (with my limited knowledge) that something is being blocked. Everything anyone has suggested to be able to see errors just gives me a 500 error over and over again.

Answer (score -2):

i advice you to use javascript for redirection

just change this :

```
header("Location: http://www.macnx.com/noflash/thanks.asp");
```

to this :

```
echo '<script>
window.location.href = "http://www.macnx.com/noflash/thanks.asp";
</script>';
```

Comment: Why? It will cause problems with the browser's history, and search engines may choke on it. If you absolutely have to redirect then HTTP redirection is the right way to go.